# Create A Custom Static Label Above Legend in R with GGPlot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have found a lot of information regarding either changing a ggplot label or adding text to the plot itself. However, I want to add text above the legend. We currently use Python to do some data manipulation and then plot it using R. Our python file outputs the data needed by the plot as well as another text file containing the settings. I want to add these settings to the plot, preferably in a box above the legend. I am confident that I can figure out how to input the text file with the settings so I need to know is how to add, for example, "Settings Test" above the legend. We are using ggplot and I have no issue either changing the legend text or adding text to the plot area (the grey area) but I have not been able to find much on adding custom static text above the legend.

Thank you.

[image]

Here is an image that I reference

Here is the code that I have tried as suggested but the output graph did not change.

```
p <- ggplot(MAE_AUC, aes(x=mae, y=auc, color=file), environment()) + geom_point(
  aes(size=count))

p2 <- p + geom_smooth(method=lm, fullrange=TRUE) +
  theme(panel.background=element_rect(fill='white', colour='black')) +
  theme(panel.grid.major=element_blank(), panel.grid.minor=element_blank()) +
  scale_colour_discrete(label=filenames)

p2$labels$fill
p2 + labs(fill=paste("StackOverflow", p2$labels$fill, sep="\n"))
```

Comment: Do you just want to change what title show up above the legend? From the documentation of ggplot2 under scales, I found a method called, `guide_legend` and it looks like you can do it with that. There are plenty of examples as well.

Comment: I don't want to add a legend per se. I want to add text above the legend. For instance, if I wanted to simply add the text "Stackoverflow" above the group legend

Comment: Gotcha. Well, it looks like you can just change the title with `guide_legend` by adding your text to its title property. Here is the URL for that method, http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/guide_legend.html. The answer provided looks pretty good as well.

Comment: I will give that a shot but I'm not sure if I want it to be formatted exactly like the legend as I feel that this may cause confusion

Comment: Okay, hope it works. I think you can change the formatting as well by changing the aesthetics.

Comment: maybe I'm reading too fast, but I didn't see a `fill` variable in your mapping, so it's not unexpected that it wouldn't show up in the legend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way to do this - basically just concatenating the contents of from `labels$fill` -- look at `str(p)` for more information.

```
library(ggplot2)

p <- ggplot(PlantGrowth, aes(x=group, y=weight, fill=group)) + geom_boxplot()

p$labels$fill
# [1] "group"

# If you just want to change the label to "test"
# p +
#   labs(fill = "test")

p +
  labs(fill = paste("StackOverflow", p$labels$fill, sep = "\n"))
```

Or you could make this more dynamic with:

```
my_static_label <- c("StackOverflow")

p +
  labs(fill = paste(my_static_label, p$labels$fill, sep = "\n"))
```

[image: results]

Comment: That does not seem to do the trick for me. I have added my code to the original question. I get the same output with and without that and I have tried it with p as well as p2